# Jenkins Choice parameter Passing to a pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

Currently I have a pipeline job which has different paramters where one of this parameters is a Choice parameter. Here is the config.xml output of that job parameter:

```xml
<hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
    <choices class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
        <a class="string-array">
            <string>f1</string>
            <string>f2</string>
            <string>f3</string>
            <string>f4</string>
        </a>
    </choices>
    <name>WHERE</name>
    <description>Something</description>
</hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
```

Now I can call this job from a pipeline via by passing a string parameter:

```
build job: "NameOfTheJob"", parameters:
  [
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH', value: "${BRANCH}"],
  ]
```

But I couldn't get a way to define the parameters for a choice parameter:

I have tried the following:

```
build job: "NameOfTheJob"", parameters:
  [
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH', value: "${BRANCH}"],
    [$class: 'ChoiceParameterValue', name: 'WHERE', value: 'F3'],
  ]
```

But this failed with the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class hudson.model.ParameterValue is named ChoiceParameterValue
```

So the question is: How to define a choice parameters in calling an other pipeline job:

```
build job: "NameOfTheJob"", parameters:
  [
    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH', value: "${BRANCH}"],
    [$class: '??????', ????],
  ]
```

Does someone has an example of such thing?

Comment: I have seen a working example that uses the below syntax:  
```build job:'NameOfTheJob', parameters: [
          string(name: 'Action', value: "test"),
          string(name: 'AnotherOption', value: "test12")
   ]       
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have seen a working example that uses the below syntax:

```
build job:'NameOfTheJob', parameters: [
      string(name: 'FirstOption', value: "test"),
      string(name: 'AnotherOption', value: "test12")
]
```

Basically, don't treat the choice parameters in a special manner, just treat them as regular string parameters.

Comment: This doesn't work with latest plugins. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433455/how-to-pass-extensible-choice-parameter-type-to-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 14):

In script mode you can also do it like this, at the moment it is bugged and it expects the choice parameters as a newline delimited string instead of an array. 
When using the Pipeline and JenkinsFile in script mode you can do a quick fix like follows:

```
properties(
    [parameters([choice(choices: ["A", "B", "C"].join("\n"),
    description: 'Some choice parameter', 
    name: 'SOME_CHOICE')])])
```

You can put this before your first node statement to add parameters to your builds.

Update: example multi select with extended choice parameter plugin in Jenkins pipeline file:

```
com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition extendedChoiceParameterDefinition = new com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition(
    "OPTION_NAME", // name
    "PT_CHECKBOX", // type
    "option1,option2,option3", // values
    null, // projectName
    null, // propertyFile
    null, // groovyScript
    null, // groovyScriptFile
    null, // bindings
    null, // groovyClasspath
    null, // propertyKey
    "option1,option2", // defaultValue
    null, // defaultPropertyFile
    null, // defaultGroovyScript
    null, // defaultGroovyScriptFile
    null, // defaultBindings
    null, // defaultGroovyClasspath
    null, // defaultPropertyKey
    null, // descriptionPropertyValue
    null, // descriptionPropertyFile
    null, // descriptionGroovyScript
    null, // descriptionGroovyScriptFile
    null, // descriptionBindings
    null, // descriptionGroovyClasspath
    null, // descriptionPropertyKey
    null, // javascriptFile
    null, // javascript
    false, // saveJSONParameterToFile
    false, // quoteValue
    10, // visible item count
    "Select your options", // description
    "," //multiSelectDelimiter
)

normalChoiceOptions = ["option1","option2"]

properties([
        parameters([
                choice(choices: normalChoiceOptions.join("\n"), description: 'Single select option', name: 'SOME_OPTION'),                
                extendedChoiceParameterDefinition
        ])
])
```

Comment: Does it work for multi select, I feel it work only for single select.

Comment: SIngle choice only, for multiple select you can use other plugin such as extended choice plugin or similar ones. The last time I did they did not have proper pipeline integration yet so coding it was a little annoying. I will add a example in my original post.

Answer (score 8):

Use `ExtendedChoiceParameterValue` instead of `ChoiceParameterValue`

e.g.

```
[$class: 'ExtendedChoiceParameterValue', name: 'param_name', value: 'param_value']
```

Comment: this is exactly what the question asked for! also using this implementation, the job that triggers another one, will fail if you provide a value, that is not listed in the choices of the called job +1

Comment: where exactly does this definition when building say an Actice Choice input?  keep getting a warning similar to this (depending on which part of the properties definition i try to declare the parameter: ```WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript': parameters```

Answer (score 8):

As documented at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters in September 2020, the documented syntax to use a choice parameter in a pipeline is:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'CHOICE',
            choices: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
            description: ''
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "Choice: ${params.CHOICE}"
                sh "echo Choice: ${params.CHOICE}"
                sh 'echo Choice: $CHOICE'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In testing, the choice defaults to the first parameter in the list, I have not looked into if this has potential to be otherwise.

All three versions of the task perform the same. Note the specific quotes used.

Comment: This is not related to the question, which is specifically for the `build` Pipeline step that triggers another Jenkins job

Comment: @Brandon It's a poorly worded question.  The triggering of another Jenkins job has nothing to do with the definition of choice values, you'd simple pass the selected value of the choice to the other pipeline. IMHO, as of 2020, this is now the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the tip of c3st7n I have tested the following:

```
build job: "NameOfTheJob", parameters:
  [
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH', value: "${BRANCH}"],
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'WHERE', value: "F3"],
  ]
```

This works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extendedChoice` instead of `ChoiceParameterValue`
like:

```
build job: 'NameOfTheJob', parameters: [extendedChoice(name: 'WHERE', value: 'F3')]
```

Jenkins docs:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/