# Pass variable from Pre step to Build Step in Maven Jenkins Job

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

I have a maven job that runs a pom.xml file with some goals I provide like below:

- Pom File: pom.xml
- goals: test -DsuiteName=testng.xml

Now I want to add a radio button parameter into this job "Run_Failed_Cases_Only", if user selects this then instead of testng.xml I want to pass testng-failed.xml file. like below:

- Pom File: pom.xml
- goals: test -DsuiteName=testng-failed.xml

So what I want is if there is any way I can use windows batch command step, that will check if "Run_Failed_Cases_Only" is selected then pass a variable $goals to the build step as per the condition below:

```html
if(Run_Failed_Cases_Only is selected)
  $goals = "test -DsuiteName=testng-failed.xml" 
else 
  $goals = test -DsuiteName=testng.xml
```

then I will use this variable in the goals text box.

Comment: You can use [Extensible Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter/) in your pipeline. You can refer this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759405/jenkins-choice-parameter-passing-to-a-pipeline-job) how to use it in pipeline code. Then, you can use the specific condition based on the choice parameter.

Comment: Thanks @souravatta but I have to create a Maven Project job only. Is there any way we can do this in Maven Project Job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using Extended Choice Parameter and providing different display name and values like below:

[image]

[image]

then used this parameter as variable in POM like below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you have created the Maven Project job, select the option **This project is parametrized** from General tab. If the Extensible Choice Plugin is not installed, install it then you can find the same here in **This project is parametrized**

Please find the screenshot below.

[image]

Then, you can use the specific condition based on the choice parameter.

**OR**

Alternatively, You can also use **Generator Choice** parameter available in **This project is parameterized** to get the result.

Please find the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Then, you can use the specific condition based on the choice.

Comment: Can you please tell me where and how do I define the condition?